# Verifying the evaluation of $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(\sin(x)) e^{\cos(x)} \frac{1}{x} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, fubini-tonelli-theorems

This problem and its solution were found [in a book by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/almost_impossible_integrals_sums_and_series_by_valean_cornel_ioan_z-lib.org_.pdf) (p. 206 ch. 3.41).
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\sin(x))e^{\cos(x)}}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}(e-1)
\end{align}

Its solution is quite clever, but seems to be a little bit quick. The problem is swiftly reduced to the following, after which the integral and the sum are switched.

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(xn)}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(xn)}{x}dx= \frac{\pi}{2}(e-1)&
\end{align}

Shouldn’t the integral converge absolutely (something like Fubini’s) for this last step to be rigorous? I also used a couple of online calculators, but they didn’t even seem convinced it converges.

Am I missing something? Is there another solution? Does it converge?
Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: There is a variant on Fubini tonelli which says if both $\int_X\int_Y$ and $\int_Y\int_X$ exist then they are the same, roughly speaking.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574916/definite-integral-possible-evaluation-using-real-methods?noredirect=1 and   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667866/show-that-int-limits-0-infty-frac-dtte-cos-t-sin-sin-t-frac-pi2e?noredirect=1